# Задание заднего фона таблицы в html при помощи css без костылей

Tags: html, css

Можно ли задать `background` для четных/не четных строчек таблицы, если у нас есть таблица состоящая например из 5 строк и 5 ячеек. Синтаксис задания фона написал правильно, и например при `table tr:hover {background: #ffffff}` все работает. Но если попытаться обратиться к элементам при помощи `table:nth-child(2n){background: #ffffff}` ничего работать не будет. Тек же пробовались варианты `table:nth-child(1){background: #ffffff}`, `table:nth-child(2n) tr{background: #ffffff}`. Все равно ничего не вышло. Реально ли реализовать задний фон для каждой четной/не четной строчки без костылей, в виде класса для этих строчек? Почему tr не считывается как дочерной элемент элемента table?

Comment: пробуйте псевдокласс добавить не к table а к tr table tr:ntd-child(2n){background: #ffffff}, так как вы добавляете условие для таблицы а не для строки

Comment: Спасибо, помогло